# Find the value of $\sqrt[3]{26}$ using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inequality, mean-value-theorem

> > Find the value of $\sqrt[3]{26}$ using Mean Value Theorem

My Try:

We choose the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$, in the interval $x \in [26,27]$. So for $0<\theta<1$, we have
$$\frac{f(27)-f(26)}{27-26}=f'(26+\theta) \Rightarrow3-f(26)=\frac{1}{3}\left(26+\theta\right)^{\frac{-2}{3}}$$

Now since $\theta<1$, we have
$$3-f(26)>\frac{1}{3}27^{\frac{-2}{3}}=\frac{1}{27} $$

$$\Rightarrow f(26)<\frac{80}{27}$$

Now I am not sure what do to next?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. What do you mean by "*the* approximate value of $\sqrt[3]{26}$"?

Comment: Yes I agree, it should be simply, "Find the value of $\sqrt[3]{26}$". I will edit it. Thanks

Comment: @AnotherUser I don’t agree. The question about approximate value is making much more sense in this context of using the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net What's about what I wrote that you don't agree with?

Comment: Approximate value is finding a value that is close to the exact value and bounding the error. This is perfectly clear.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, it is perfectly clear *when a bounding error is provided*, which is not the case here.

Comment: @AnotherUser It is part of the question to propose a bounding of the error using MVT.